# How can I disable problem underlines for unused variables with the Rust Analyzer VS Code extension and instead highlight it gray?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I am coding in Rust by using VS Code, but the variable that i'm not used shows a ugly wavy underline, i want to disable it and just make my unused variables being gray which seems like IntelliJ IDEA shows unused functions.

VS Code:

[image: VS Code]

goland

[image: goland]

Comment: squiggles are created by the compiler or linter

Comment: you can set the color of the warning squiggle equal to the editor background

Comment: what does the error/warning text say? It should also mention the creator of the squiggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [Chayim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76575803/11107541) you can change change the warnings to hints, which have a more subtle visual cue. I'm not sure of a way to remove all underline-related visual cues. Like so:

```json
"rust-analyzer.diagnostics.warningsAsHint": [
   "unused_variables"
],
```

As for highlighting it grey, the Rust Analyzer extension doesn't provide any dedicated semantic token for unused things at the time of this writing (I checked using the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command). [Semantic highlighting has a mechanism for "modifiers"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers). There isn't yet a modifier for unused things, but there's a feature-request for that here: [SemanticTokensModifier: Add `unused` token modifier #604](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/604). You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. If/when it does get implemented, you'd then also have to wait for the Rust Analyzer extension to make use of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can make the name grey, but you can avoid the squiggles by changing the settings. In settings.json of VS Code:

```rust
{
    "rust-analyzer.diagnostics.warningsAsHint": [
        "dead_code",
        "unused_variables"
    ]
}
```

Comment: what's the `dead_code` part for?

Comment: @starball Unused functions, types, structs, fields...